# как оптимизировать туман войны для игры пакман

Tags: python, pygame

что бы сделать туман войны, я на каждом шаге пакмана перерисовываю поле считаю расстояние от каждого пикселя до пакмана, и расстояния до прошлых координат пакмана, возможно надо использовать surface для оптимизации, если да то как?

```
def visibility():
    pacman_history.append([pacman.x, pacman.y])
    for x in range(SIZE):
        for y in range(SIZE):
            distances = []
            for p in pacman_history:
                distance = ((x - p[0]) ** 2 + (y - p[1]) ** 2) ** 0.5
                distances.append(distance)
            out = 0
            for d in distances:
                if d >= pacman.visibility:
                out = out + 1
            if out == distances.__len__():
                sc.set_at((x, y), (0, 0, 0))
pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно переделать алгоритм так, чтобы вместо просчёта видимости объекта для каждой позиции, в которой персонаж когда-либо был, просчитывать видимость только для текущей позиции, а затем сохранять эти данные. Судя по вашему коду, открытый объект не может быть скрыт, а значит после его открытия мы изменяем свойство видимости класса (если объекты представлены в виде классов) или добавляем объект в список "видимых", а затем в цикле отрисовки проверяем это свойство. Это решение ускорит код во много раз!